# passing null in object constructor for property of type long

Tags: java, long-integer

i have a class `MyClass` which has two properties, one of type `String` and one of type `long` (im using lombok to have all arguments constructor)

```
@AllArgsConstructor
public class MyClass{
    private String sth;
    private long id;

    //some methods
}
```

now in my test factory class i want to have method to create object of `MyClass` with `String` set to something and `id` set to null

```
public static MyClass getMyClassWithNullId() {
        return new Myclass("some string", null);
}
```

however the above code can not compile:
`The constructor MyClass(String, null) is undefined`

Why can't i pass null to long? (any long value instead of null is correct)

EDIT: private field `id` of MyClass was suposed to be `Long` instead of `long`, which solves everything

Comment: Use `Long` instead of `long`. primitives don't access null value.

Comment: you can use object type `Long` instead of primitive type `long` as @Eran advised. But be aware that in cases you are trying to use this Long value in an arithmetic expression, that involves [autoboxing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html), you'll get `NullPointerException`.

Comment: @RafaelOsipov what does autoboxing have to do with it ?? ;)

Comment: You didn't provide any constructors. What happens when somebody provides `null` for the id, what will you assign the field `id` to be?

Comment: as stated by @Eran, when i read my question again i noticed that i used lower case ``long`` which is primitive instead of warper class ``Long``

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your constructor should look like

```
public void MyClass(String str,Long param){}
```

then call like  `new MyClass("hello",null);` will be valid

Comment: Or he calls it with ("hello", 0). Your answer sounds like that is the only solution to his problem.

Comment: 0 isn't the same as null

Comment: @GhostCat  0 means a value and null means no reference to this instance, i hope this is clear to you.

Comment: It depends what he intendeds **id** to mean. If he **means** it to be a **long**, then there is no point in passing **null**. You make the assumption that his attempt to pass null means that he should be using a Long. I am only saying that maybe he doesn't know what he is doing. And then your solution is of the same value as passing 0.

Comment: @GhostCat and u are making some strage assumptions as well. If `(id ==null`) maybe `id` will be autogenerated..... simple usecase.

As for "maybe null is the same as passing 0" assumption - yes, maybe. But this is irrelevant to the question.

Comment: @Antoniossss And then the reasonable design would be to allow for a constructor that only takes a string; to avoid having client code that passes in a null. Passing null to indicate: "do whatever you want" sounds like a rather bad id.

Comment: @GhostCat and then this is not question about the design. I understand your point, and agree with it, but it is off-topic.

Comment: @Antoniossss In that sense, it is a question of *style* - as in: I think answers should help to solve the real problem behind a question. And if the question translates to "fix my bad design"; then the answer is "change your design"; not "this is how you workaround your bad design".

Answer (score -1):

ok, nevermind, `long` is a primitive type and can not be null, used warper class `Long` solves it